# How to use execution strategy executing stored procedures with Oracle, .NET 6, EF 6, IOC and repository pattern?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

Intermittently experiencing database connection issues in Prod due to pooling. Due to very strict guidance on pools, would like to take advantage of connection resiliency. We're using .NET 6, EF 6 and Oracle. However, very few Oracle examples online so not sure whether connection resiliency code should be at repository level where `DbContext` passed in via IOC or elsewhere.

In the following code, where do I place execution strategy code:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(builder.UseOracle(base._connString)
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true));
}
```

Comment: It's not clear which connection resiliency strategy you're referring to by this line f code. That line is not related to connection resiliency.

Comment: protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(builder.UseOracle(base._connString).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
                                        );
        }

Comment: I'm trying to determine if the OnConfiguring method (C#) is the correct place to code the execution strategy for Oracle. Or, is it better placed in a config file? Either way, an example would be helpful.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea of how to inject connection resiliency into the code block above?